# How to check only hasData attribute exist in if condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I check only data attribute from div in if condition...

here is my code ==>

```
if ($(selector).hasData('data-name')){
}
```

in this code I have received error that `hasData` not a function.

Comment: hello there thanks to reply but i want only check if there data attribute i.e -data-text="text" so i want only check data-text not the value

Answer (score 0):

The `jQuery.hasData()` method provides a way to determine if an element currently has any values that were set using `jQuery.data()`. If there is no data object associated with an element, the method returns `false`; otherwise it returns `true`.
From jQuery official docs.
Refer this [link](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.hasData/) for more info.

To get the data attribute of a element use the code below

```
console.log($(selector).attr("#data-name").val())
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.attr()` method gets the attribute value for only the first element in the matched set. See this [link](http://api.jquery.com/attr/). It returns `undefined` if the attributs is not set.

```
if ($(selector).attr('data-name')){
   //handle has attribute condition here
}
```